# IF Function with Drop-Down List (Data Validation)

Tags: excel, vba, validation, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I wanted to do VBA for when user select something or write something, IF FUNCTION will process the user input and on specific cell drop-down list will appear with the selections. Please refer below attached:

[image]

So when TYPE OF TANK is HORIZONTAL then list for TYPE OF HEAD will appear in D4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called dependent data validation and can be achieved without VBA, using named ranges and Indirect() in the Data validation list formula. For more details refer to

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html